# dynamically generate form with array of text boxes in django

Tags: django, django-forms

How to dynamically generate array of text boxes, to get multiple input texts with name
`document_line_value[]` using django forms?,I can do it only if I generate form code manually without using django form,but I'd like to use django form for validation and other useful things.

```
from django import forms

class EditDocumentForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, document_lines, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditDocumentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for document_line in document_lines:
            self.fields['document_line_value[]'] = forms.FloatField(label='value')
```

It displays only the last element:

```
<input type='text' name='document_line_value[]' />
```

I want to have several such arrays on form that which is a row in table:

```
<tr>
  <td><input type='text' name='document_line_value[]' /></td>
  <td><input type='text' name='document_line_id[]' /></td>
  <td> <input type='text' name='document_line_comment[]' /></td>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type='text' name='document_line_value[]' /></td>
  <td><input type='text' name='document_line_id[]' /></td>
  <td> <input type='text' name='document_line_comment[]' /></td>
<tr>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/formsets/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the [`FormSet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) class.

It should be noted that the `field[]` syntax is a PHP feature which is generally only supported by PHP. There is no technical reason for requiring to use `[]` after a field name.

Example:

```
from django import forms

class Document(forms.Form):
    line_value = forms.CharField()
    line_id = forms.IntegerField()
    line_comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())

DocumentFormSet = formsets.formset_factory(Document)

def your_view(request):
    formset = DocumentFormSet()
```

Comment: Will MultiValueField allow to get array of input text?

Comment: Could you please give example of MultiValueField? Can it help in my case?

Comment: Does forset generate form with the same name attributes?

Comment: @Oleg: sorry, I misunderstood, the `MultiValueField` won't help in your case. You should use a formset instead.

Comment: Will FormSet allow to generate table like form with array of values, and prefill each form (row in table) with different value?

Comment: @Oleg: yes, you can view example results from the formset system here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-initial-data-with-a-formset

Comment: But it will populate fields of all forms with the same value, right? Can I populate field of each form seperately?

Comment: Could you please explain you example?

Comment: Your example doesn't generates the same names, but like id_form-0-document_line_value which is not what we need: <tr><th><label for="id_form-0-document_line_value">value:</label></th><td><input id="id_form-0-document_line_value" name="form-0-document_line_value" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_form-0-document_line_comment">comment:</label></th><td><input id="id_form-0-document_line_comment" name="form-0-document_line_comment" type="text" /><input id="id_form-0-document_line_id" name="form-

Comment: Correct, this is the way Django handles multiple forms. If you want to use Django forms you will have to use this method. You can create a converter to support php output but that's not the best idea imho...

Comment: Alternatively you could simply join the results from `request.POST.getlist` like so: `l=request.POST.getlist; zip(l('document_line_value[]'),l('document_line_id[]'),l('document_line_comment[]'))`

Comment: It will join the results of the different fields in 1 list of results. That should give you the results you need but you don't have the form validation that way.

Comment: It's not possible to populate fields of each form in formset with individual values, right?

Comment: If you use the keys as used in the form it will be possible. Is there any reason not to use a similar naming system though? Just look at the source for the formset class to see how it works: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/formsets.py

Comment: Formsets doesn't generate elements with the same name, but with names something like this name_0, name_1.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to dynamically create on django form a set of elemenets with the same name.

Comment: Yes, but not using the unmodified formset library. If you modify the `add_index` function you can do it, but you'll have to modify how it gets the results as well: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/formsets.py#L370

Comment: Do you mean to subclass and redefine add_index?

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean :)